# React Error Boundary Not working when using Provider

Tags: reactjs, error-handling

I am using react-error-bundary to implement the error boundries in my Recat.js Application ,But one issue i am facing when i use redux, if i try throw any error manually using built in new Error class , Error boundry fallback Component is not showing ,instead same ui  is showing but UI not responding without hard refreshing.

//Index.js

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import App from "./app/Index";
    import store from "store/store";
    import { Provider } from "react-redux";
    import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
    import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
    import { persistor } from "store/store";
    import { Spinner } from "components";
    
    import FallbackUi from "components/ErrorBoundaryFallbackComponent";
    import { ErrorBoundary } from "react-error-boundary";
    
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
        <ErrorBoundary
          FallbackComponent={FallbackUi}
          resetKeys={[history.location.pathname]}
        >
          
            {/* <Provider store={store}> */}
            <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
              
              <App />
            </PersistGate>
            {/* </Provider> */}
        </ErrorBoundary>
      </Suspense>,
      document.getElementById("root")
    );
```

//redux Store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { persistStore, persistReducer, createTransform } from "redux-persist";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
import { setupListeners } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query";
import { apiSlice } from "apiHelpers/ApiSlice";
import sessionStorage from "redux-persist/lib/storage/session";



const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  transforms: [transformCircular],
  storage: sessionStorage,
};


const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      sentryReduxEnhancer,
      serializableCheck: false,
    }).concat([apiSlice.middleware]),
  devTools: true,
});



setupListeners(store.dispatch);
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
export default store;
```

//App.js

```
import React from "react";

function App() {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        throw new Error("Test");
      }}
      className="flex items-center"
    >
      {" "}
      Throw custom Error
    </button>
  );
}

export default App;
```